# Regex test returning true when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem with regex. I would like to make a test to see if a string contains a word char. If it contains a word char it should alert true. And for some reason this alerts true. What am i doing wrong? I'm pretty positive that this shouldn't alert true.

```
if (/\w/.test('23')) {alert('true')}
```

Comment: `"2"` and `"3"` are [alphanumeric characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: `\w` doesn't mean "word character;" it means "alphanumeric character," as @NobleMushtak pointed out.

Comment: /\w[^0-9]/.test('9999')

Answer (score 7):

`/\w/` tests for alphanumeric characters (including the underscore). Instead, make your own regular expression that contains only alphabetic characters:

```
/[A-Za-z]/.test("hi"); //true
/[A-Za-z]/.test("HI!"); //true
/[A-Za-z]/.test("23"); //false
```